# Generate random 2d array with special symbols in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to generate a random 2D array, which is filled randomly with special symbols.
Now the problem is that when I compile my code, it prints my array, but the symbols are filled from top to bottom. That is wrong, it has to start filling them from bottom. And the other problem is that each special symbol "!@#$" should be filled in equally, which is determined by the number of rows of an array -> "field". So for example when an array is generated with 4 rows, then each symbol should be randomly scattered exactly 4 times.

I've been trying to fix those two issues, but I just don't know how. So I'd be very thankfull for someone, who could point me towards fix and help me understand where my mistakes are.

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    int y, x, a=0, b=0;
    y = (rand()%(8-3+1)+3); // y = number of rows
    x = (rand()%(8-4+1)+4); // x = number of columns
    char field[y][x];

    const char* symbol = "!@#$";

    int r;       // determines how many symbols are used based on 
    if(x == 7)   // number of columns - 2 = number of symbols used
        r = x-3;
    else if(x > 6)
        r = x/2;
    else
        r = x-2;

    int randnum1 = (rand()%x), randnum2 = (rand()%x);

    if(randnum1 == randnum2) {  // takes 2 random indexes from number of columns
        randnum2 += 1;          // and fills them with blanks 
    }
    if(randnum2 >= x) {
        randnum2 -= 2;
    } 

    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 =0; // checks if same number of all
                                               // symbols is used
    for(a = 0; a < y; a++) {
        printf("\n %d |", a+1);  
        for(b = 0; b < x; b++) {     
            if(b == randnum1 || b == randnum2) {
                field[a][b] = ' ';
                printf(" %c |", field[a][b]);
            }
            else {
                field[a][b] = symbol[rand()%r];
 
                int sum1 = num1+num2+num3+num4;  // sum checks if the total max
                int sum2 = y * r;                // number of symbols has been used

                if(field[a][b] == '!')
                    num1 += 1;
                if(field[a][b] == '@')
                    num2 += 1;
                if(field[a][b] == '#')
                    num3 += 1;
                if(field[a][b] == '$')
                    num4 += 1;

                if(sum1 < sum2) {
                    if((num1 < y) || (num2 < y) || (num3 < y) || (num4 < y)) {
                        printf(" %c |", field[a][b]);
                    }        
                    else {
                        field[a][b] = ' ';        
                        printf(" %c |", field[a][b]);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    field[a][b] = ' ';        
                    printf(" %c |", field[a][b]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    for(a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
        printf("    ");
        for(b = 0; b < x; b++) {
            printf("--- ");
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    for(b = 0; b < 1; b++) {
        printf("    ");
        for(b = 0; b < x; b++) {
            printf(" %d  ", b+1);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because some variables `rn1`... are not declared, please show minimum working example with expected output.

Comment: When you want a "random" that is not exactly *random* (like the distribution of your `"!@#$"`) the usual solution is to fill an array with all the elements and required repetitions, then *shuffle* that array ... `/*pseudo-code*/char everything[17] = "!@#$!@#$!@#$!@#$"; shuffle(everything, 16);`

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be compilable now, and all the headers are included also. I should've checked it before posting, my bad. @AndreasWenzel

Comment: Yes, but the array size is randomized every time i run the code, and so the amount of symbols can also change depending on number of rows. @pmg

Comment: @PaulAtreides: Then you will have to generate that array at run-time, instead of compile-time. Since the size of that array is also dependant on the number of lines, you may have to use `malloc` (or a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which I don't recommend) instead of using a fixed-size array. You can shuffle using [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).